# stream to output the buffered data back to the browser as download in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, google-api, google-drive-api

I am getting file content from google drive api v3 in stream.

> Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
>
> request.Download(stream)

Above lines download file content to stream. So far so good.

Now i want to download this stream in file on client browser. I have gone through some sample code and all of them download file from http response. When i use that script and pass my stream, but my aspx file gets downloaded. I mean the script is written on test.aspx and after running that script empty file gets downloaded and name of file is test.aspx

Please share some solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the  issue of it being empty, you *probably* forgot to rewind the stream; add:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

before you hand it over.

For the issue of the name: you need to use the `content-disposition` http header to give it a better one. This *may* already be available in the `request.Download` method as an optional parameter. If not: just add the http header yourself. For example [from rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html)

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, stream.position = 0 works for me but now the file keep on downloading. i can see file size as 819 KB but downloading never stops (test.jpg.crdownload)

Comment: @Anjum well did you set the content-length? Basically, you need to look at the http traffic to diagnose this

Comment: currently i am leaving it empty, what should be content length ?? Stream length ??

Comment: Excellent, file gets downloaded819/819 KB downloaded. but that image file not view able, when i open that image, it says "file appears to be damaged, corrupted or it is too large"

Comment: @Anjum that suggests that you didn't  tell the web framework not to render the regular response alongside the download. Check for html in the response when looking in a tool like fiddler - it shouldn't be there.

Comment: In network log it says "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://localhost:27876/test.aspx"."

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Anjum without seeing what your payload looks like in "fiddler", all I can do is guess: but it looks like you need to change the content-type header, and I still speculate that you're sending the *regular* response  down the pipe in addition to the file